# How to load the contents of a static HTML file into a DIV using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a bunch of static HTML files containing textual data:

```
/a.html
/b.html
/c.html
```

and a select/dropdown box (`#loadExternal`) on my main page.

Using jQuery, how can I use the `onChange` event of the select/dropdown to trigger the appropriate external page to be loaded into my `container` DIV?

```
<html>

<select id="loadExternal">
    <option id="a" value="a" selected="selected">Load a.html</option>
    <option id="b" value="b">Load b.html</option>
    <option id="c" value="c">Load c.html</option>
</select>

<div id="container">
</div>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$("#loadExternal").change( function () {
   page = $(this).val();
   $("#container").load(page + ".html")
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the change event to the select box. Get the value of the current selection. Use the [**`.load()`**](http://api.jquery.com/load/) event to load the page.

```
$("#loadExternal").change(function(){
    var pageToLoad = this.value + ".html";
    $("#container").load(pageToLoad);
});
```

See a [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/CRm4L/)

Comment: wont the pageToLoad var end up being loadExternal.html?

Comment: @Cole, no it will be the value of the selected option.

Comment: ah it said this.id when I commented.  Should be fine now.